# http request from ABAP to IIS 10 remains zipped when processed in PHP

Tags: php, iis, compression, httprequest, abap

We are sending XML-files from ABAP to IIS 10-webserver by http-request which is processed by PHP. Uncompressed sent data works well, but if I switch on compression in ABAP, PHP receives scrambled (binary compressed?) data, which is much smaller than the original data, so I think it remains compressed. According to my understanding the IIS should uncompress the data before giving it to PHP, so I shouldn't care about this thing.

ABAP code for sending request

```
method send_xstring_by_https.     
     data string_content type string.
     do 200 times.
        string_content = |{ string_content }this is an example XML - some Umlauts: üöä.|.
     enddo.

     "Content gets the type xstring
     content = cl_abap_codepage=>convert_to( source = |<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><someData>{ string_content }</someData>|
                                             codepage = |ISO-8859-1| ).
     DATA: o_client TYPE REF TO if_http_client.

     cl_http_client=>create_by_url( EXPORTING
                                      url     = |<your_url>|
                                    IMPORTING
                                      client  = o_client ).


     o_client->request->set_version( version = if_http_request=>co_protocol_version_1_1 ).
     o_client->request->set_method( if_http_request=>CO_REQUEST_METHOD_GET ).
     o_client->request->set_content_type( 'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1' ).
     data(length_content) = xstrlen( content ).
     o_client->propertytype_accept_compress = if_http_client=>co_enabled.
***     "Compression remove *** to set compression
***     o_client->set_compression( if_http_client=>co_compress_in_all_cases ).
     o_client->request->SET_DATA(
       exporting
         DATA               = content    " Binary Data
         LENGTH             = length_content    " Length of Binary Data
     o_client->send( if_http_client=>co_timeout_default ).

     o_client->receive( EXCEPTIONS
                          HTTP_COMMUNICATION_FAILURE = 1
                          HTTP_INVALID_STATE = 2
                          HTTP_PROCESSING_FAILED = 3
                      ).
  endmethod.
```

PHP-code for receiving

```
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents('php://input');

    if (!file_put_contents(<local_path_and_filename>, $content)) {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
?>
```

The example will send uncompressed data, to send compressed data, remove the ***. It creates a long xml file, if the xml is to short, it seems it will be never compressed. Try to set the loop to 1 times and compression on for testing.

I looked for compression settings for received requests, but found none. The only settings for compression I found are for sending requests by IIS, which I switched on (dynamic and static compression).

I tried some different content types, like e.g. application/XML, but doesn't work.

Editing 23:43:
Isn't the way it should work the following:

- abap-request sets uncompressed content
- SAP-Netweaver sends the request and is allowed for sending compressed content.
- SAP-Netweaver contacts the IIS-Server and they negotiate if and what method for compression is to use
- SAP-Netweaver sends compressed request
- IIS receives compressed request and uncompress it
- PHP gets uncompressed data

Thinking of this process I don't know what to change in my PHP-Code

Comment: I think `propertytype_accept_compress = if_http_client=>co_enabled` (default) just sets the HTTP header field `Accept-Encoding` of the request to `gzip` (SAP Help Portal: *`You can set PROPERTYTYPE_ACCEPT_COMPRESS to the value CO_DISABLED so that the partner can send its data in non-compressed form`*. The content is "scrambled" ("mojibake") because you send binary data. I think the problem is only in your PHP code.

Comment: @sandra rossi: You are right that I should specifiy SAP better, so the code is written in ABAP, but maybe the underlying SAP Netweaver 6.0 has to be configured to provide the functions for sending http requests to act like a webserver.

Comment: We have two different compression settings here, `o_client->propertytype_accept_compress = if_http_client=>co_enabled` is for allowing the asked server to send the answer compressed. We send XML-Files but they could contain special character. e.g. Umlauts (we are a german company), encoded in ISO-8859-1, to avoid problems we send it in binary format. if we send this file uncompressed, all works fine. If we switch on compression with the other method `o_client->set_compression( if_http_client=>co_compress_in_all_cases )` php gets the binary code.

Comment: Avoid [tag:netweaver] here (Java, ABAP, ...), it's not software hence no version, is "marketing" platform name. Widest ABAP-related tag is [tag:sap-basis] (see URL in tag info of [tag:sap]).

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question well. Do you mean you want to use `set_compression` only and your IIS server doesn't understand it? From https://blogs.sap.com/2007/02/28/avoiding-dual-compression-in-sap-web-as, I can find interesting information (possibly, don't set `content-length`). Also, what is this "binary format" to transport ISO-8859-1, is it UTF-8? Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can copy/paste to test it. Please post the HTTP request you receive from ABAP.

Comment: extend the examples, it should be ready to test.

Comment: Your ABAP code is 50% fine: `üöä` are encoded in hex `FCF6E4`, so it's valid ISO-8859-1, but you send a wrong content type, it should be `text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1`. The size may be a problem if you have a low value on `icm/HTTP/max_request_size_kb` (see `RZ11` and ICM log).

Comment: I tested with your suggestion for the content type, but no change so far. I checked the Parameter, it is 102400 KB, so more than enough for my request ( less then 10MB).

Comment: To finish the investigation at SAP side, post directly a same HTTP request to IIS/PHP (from Postman or whatever).

Comment: I tried Postman, but i have no chance to send a compressed request, even if I set the explicit header "Content-Encoding: gzip". Taking the XML and compress it manually to send the self-compressed message seems not to be useful for a test, because if IIS do not the decmpression I still not know if my request is to strange. I have an idea for a workaround I will try tomorrow.

Comment: At SAP side, you may also do an ICF Server Recording (trace) to (try to) intercept the outbound request: `SICF` > Edit > Recorder > Activate/deactivate/display. Be sure to display the view of sent requests, and then to display "In New Session" (I have difficulties with other options). PS: I know that `SICF` doesn't work for special things like Chunked transfer encoding, fingers crossed for the compression.

Comment: @SandraRossi I tried to do a recording, but i got no recordings. I also have no entry for my outgoing request in SICF. I tried / and /* as path in the dialog, both with no results. I'm not sure, if the SICF recording the right thing for outgoing requests, it seems a thing to be a recording tool for incoming requests. I tried to find a recording/trace in SM59 but found none. I have found a workaround that works for me, see my posting, so we could close this case, but I'm still interested in a "proper" solution. Many thanks for your help and effort!!!

Comment: `SICF` can record incoming and outgoing traffic. You must use the *server* recording for outgoing traffic (SAP server acting as server), not the *client* recording (SAP server acting as client). I think I have indicated the right menu in my previous comment (i.e. don't choose the menu Client > Recorder).

Comment: Nice. Could you post your workaround as a distinct answer please? (not in the question)

Comment: I used the recorder following your description and also your answer in this blog: https://blogs.sap.com/2006/04/05/icf-recording-a-possibility-for-analysing/

Comment: Sorry my bad, I just said the opposite. In fact, it's the Client Recorder to be used (ABAP acting as client, calling an external server...): menu Client > Recorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem.

I try to decompress the content in the PHP script. If decompression is not possible, the content will be write to file directly. That worked for me:

```
    $receivedContent = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $contentToWrite = gzdecode($receivedContent);
    if (!$contentToWrite) {
        $contentToWrite = $receivedContent;
    }
    if (!file_put_contents(<local_path_and_filename>, $contentToWrite)) {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
```